# Как сделать фильтр данных с полями?

Tags: html, javascript

Подскажите, как сделать фильтр данных с полями 1-input (любое число) 2-select (выбор из 5 чисел) 3-radio buttom (да,нет) 4-radio buttom(да,нет), понимаю что это всё нужно в массив как то закинуть но совсем не понимаю как фильтровать

Comment: @нгш, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы (в частности какие данные у вас есть, в каком виде). Опишите что вы сделали сами, что не получилось. Создайте заготовку-пример на http://jsfiddle.net.  
Не забывайте принимать ответы, у вас всего 9% принятых ответов.

Comment: Это скорее ко мне претензия:)

Comment: @knes подскажите еще такой момент- в первом инпуте у вас указана строго цифра, а как в этот инпут внести цифры что бы они например фильтровались в первом массиве от 3000 а во втором от 5000 и тд

Comment: Напишите подробно какие исходные данные, какой ввод с формы и что хотите получить в итоге. Лучше прямо в JSFiddle: меняете myvar, в комментариях указываете значения для формы и данные, которые должны из myvar таким образом  отфильтроваться.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Akt85/
@knes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть данные:

```
var myvar = [  
  {name:"data1",val1:100500,val2:3,val3:true,val4:false},  
  {name:"data2",val1:800,val2:1,val3:false,val4:false},  
  {name:"data3",val1:777,val2:2,val3:false,val4:true}  
]
```

Есть фильтр-массив:

```
var filter = [777,false,true]

var filtered_data = [];
for(i=0;i<myvar.length;i++){
  data_accepted = true;
  for(j=0;j<filter.length;j++){
    if(filter[j]!=myvar[i]['val'+j]){
      data_accepted = false;
    }
  }
  if(data_accepted){
    filtered_data.push(myvar[i]);
  }
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: а хтмл код будет стандартным?

Comment: и было бы не плохо если бы чуть чуть подсказали логику работы, например {name:"data3",val1:777,val2:2,val3:false,true}   почему тут true и что var filter = [777,false,true]
 это за строчка

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a3X7w/

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, один вопрос остался, ведь он в конце должен выдать или data1 и тд., правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да. Если данные подходят под фильтр - да.
Но вы можете вывести все, что угодно аналогичным образом, это для примера.

Входные данные хранятся в переменной myvar, их вы тоже можете составить самостоятельно.

Comment: огромнейшие спасибо, додумал